# How to set up this view of commerce orders...?

Tags: commerce, views

Really hope someone can help me with this as am completely stuck, sorry it's a bit long but I don't know what else to do...

I'm working on a commerce site for a client that offers blocks of pilates classes. Users will purchase blocks of 6 classes in order to book onto them.

I have one product in the store called 'standard-6-block' at a price of £45.

I then have a product display called 'Class (Block)'.

The Class (Block) nodes will list 6 dates using just a text field with an unlimited number allowed (although each block will just have 6 classes added)

Blocks of classes run for 6 weeks, hence the 6 dates in each node, and will be added every week.

For example there may be one Class (Block) node with 11/01/2017, 18/01/2017, 25/01/2017, 1/02/2017, 8/02/2017, 15/02/2017 dates.

There will then be another node added a week later with 18/01/2017, 25/01/2017, 1/02/2017, 8/02/2017, 15/02/2017, 22/02/2017 dates.

This is because users may start blocks of classes at different times so we've agreed blocks will be added each week.

I now need my client to be able to run reports using a views page to show who has booked on to each class. (Not each block of classes (node) but individual classes in blocks (dates in the 'Class Dates' field in the node).

I've created one test order in my store which has purchased just one block of classes. There are currently 4 blocks of classes available to purchase on the website.

My view settings are:
View of: Commerce Orders

Relationships:
Commerce Order: Line items, (Line items referenced by commerce_line_items) Commerce Line item: Product, Commerce Order: Owner, (Products referenced by commerce_product) Commerce Product: Referencing Node, Commerce Order: Payment Transaction

Filters:
(Node referencing products from field_product_type) Content: Class Dates (exposed) and is REQUIRED!

Now when I run the report and enter a date for example 18/01/2017, the view doesn't just show the ONE order in the store IE this user has registered and paid for this class, it shows all 4 of the nodes that have been added.

Really hope that makes sense...? Thank you so much for taking the time to help me

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I need to make every block of classes individual products in the store and use 'Auto product display' module to automatically create the node displays.  Then have to create a view that lists the commerce products rather than node displays